# Can I take family leave in NYS if my employment date started after date of birth?

Tags: employment, new-york-state

If someone has a baby in January, and starts at a company in February, are they eligible for the [state-legislated paid family leave](https://paidfamilyleave.ny.gov/) once the required time has accrued, or must they need to have been an employee on the date of birth?